# Answers that are specific to OP's singular circumstances

Tags: discussion, answers

So, this question "[Get coordinates at specific point in time - java edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360531/get-coordinates-at-specific-point-in-time-java-edition)", asks about how to get the world co-ords of a last known location. The question is fine, and an answer has been provided, which is also fine.

However, the OP came back to [answer the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360599/73976):

> just went to the folder for my mod, then to the logs folder, and found the log for the console. The console actually says where I spawned, and it was inside my house.
>
> So I went to `My Mod 1/run/logs` and found the appropriate one.

This suggests that the OP had a pre-installed mod that had captured this information?

I'm not sure how this situation affects the answer. Sure, for *this specific situation*, it answers the question, but *without* that specific mod (or a similar one), the only applicable answer is [brododragon's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/360542/73976).

So, to clarify, my question is how should the answer, that was provided by the OP be handled? It does answer the question, and (if they do provide the specific information for the mod), it's not exactly a *bad* answer, it just seems way too specific.

Answer (score 1):

**As any other answer**: let the community sort it out by their (lack of) votes.

If the answer answers the question (which i.c. it does), there is no reason to treat it differently, no matter how specific it is. You can leave comments to emphasize this peculiarity, or downvote it.

Comment: What exactly is misleading about marking an answer as accepted? If it worked best for OP, that's what the accepted checkmark is for.

Comment: But it doesn't. All it means is that the answer worked best for the OP.